# Google Analytics Event Tracking with /__utm.gif

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I use this URL to report an event to google-analytics:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmac=UA-12345678-9&utmcc=&utmcs=UTF-8&utmhn=www.example.com&utmwv=4.8.1&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.coml%2Freferer&utmt=event&utme=5(Out*action*label)(1)
```

In Analytics, I definied a goal like:

```
Goal Name: Out
Goal Type: Event
Goal Details: 
Categorie is euql to: Out
Action: [no selection]
Label: [no selection]
Value: [no selection]
Goal Value: Use the actual event value
```

But: No goals arrive in Analytics. What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you use that url directly or through an API? You know that gif request is not a supported protocol right?

Comment: It is possible to fire the __utm.gif directly, but you have to construct the correct params. I don't understand the `(1)` at the end of your code. As far I know, the event's syntax is: `utme=5(<category>*<action>*<label>*<value>)`. `<value>` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#basicDebugging where it says:

```
3. Ensure that the utmp parameter is present.
4. Ensure that the utmcc parameter is present and non-empty.
   In the case of an empty utmcc parameter, no cookie data is sent, and the request is ignored.
```

It looks like your request does not do either of those.